# Does it make sense for a constant function to have infinitely many critical points?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So I've been pondering over constant functions, that is, functions of the form

$$ f(x)=c$$

where $c$ is a constant. $f'(x) = 0$, so every value you put into $f$ is a critical point. That means there are infinitely many critical points.

But does it make sense for it to have infinitely many critical points (and that every point, everywhere is a critical point?)

Comment: Why would it not make sense?  There are other functions with infinitely many critical points as well (periodic functions, for example).

Comment: Yes, that’s fine. $\sin (x)$ is perhaps a more meaningful example of a function with infinitely many critical points.

Comment: Recall that local and global maximums and minimums occur at critical points.  Every point of a constant function is a maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about it is that constant functions are flat, so every point is a "maxima/minima".

And, local and global maxima and minima occur at critical points. So, it does make sense.

---

> $\sin(x)$ is a more meaningful example of a function with infinitely many critical points

Comment: Check the comments by Chubby. It is more meaningful

Comment: @crystal_math What is?