# Number of Critical Point of $|x-1|+|x|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) =|x-1|+|x|$. Find the number of critical points of the function in its domain.

According to me the definition of critical point is the point on the function where either $f'(x) =0$ or $f'(x) $ does not exist.

In the interval $(-\infty, 0) $
$$f(x) =1-2x$$
$$f'(x) =-2 \neq 0$$
Similarly in interval $(1, \infty) $
$$f(x) =2x-1$$
$$f'(x) =2 \neq 0$$
The problem comes in the interval $[0, 1]$. Firstly is it trivial the the derivative of the function does not exist at points $\{0, 1\}$

In the interval (0, 1)
$$f(x) =1$$
$$f'(x) =0 \forall x \in (0, 1) $$

So the critical points to this function all reals in the interval $[0, 1]$. Hence the function has an infinite number of critical points.

But the answer to this problem is given as $2$.

Why is this happening? Is my definition  of critical points incomplete or wrong? Or maybe the answer to the problem is given wrong.

Comment: For $0<x<1$ your function is $f(x)=(1-x)+x=1$ so it is perfectly differentiable there.

Comment: Yes! But it's not differentiable at points $0,1$. I have mentioned points $0,1$ not the interval $[0, 1]$

Comment: Right, that's $2$ points.  Just as in the official solution.

Comment: What did you mean when you said "the critical points to this function all reals in the interval $[0,1]$?"  As I said, and as you agreed, it is perfectly differentiable in the interior of that interval.

Comment: It's differentiable but the derivative is zero so it satisfies the condition of critical point.

Comment: I would say the function has infinitely many critical points. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947595/does-it-make-sense-for-a-constant-function-to-have-infinitely-many-critical-poin)

Comment: Ah, got it.  Yes, in that case I agree with you.  I thought you were just counting singular points (and I expect the official source was thinking the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Critical point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=The%20corresponding%20critical%20value%20is%20f(0)%20%3D%200.,point%2C%20with%20critical%20value%200.):  A point $x_0\in I$ is a critical point of the function $f:I\to\Bbb{R}$ if $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0$ or $f'(x_0) =0$.

In other words critical points of $f$ are all non differentiable points (singular points) and [stationary points](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) of $f$.

$f$ is differentiable on $(-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty) $ with non zero derivatives.

$f$ is not differentiable on $\{0, 1\}$

$f$ is differentiable on $(0, 1) $ and $f'=0$ on $(0, 1) $

[image]

$f(x) =1$ on $(0, 1) $ and tangents of $f$ is parallel to the $x$-axis.

> Non differentiable ponits(singular points) : $0$ and $1$

> Stationary points: $(0, 1) $

> Critical points : $[0, 1]$

---

Comment: I like that you noted that that entire interval is stationary.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
|x - 1| + |x| = |1 - x| + |x| \geq 1 - x + x = 1
\end{align*}

Comment: How does this help?